# Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures

Tags: javascript, node.js

I find myself assigning "this" to a variable so I can easily use it in callbacks and closures.

Is this bad practice? Is there a better way of referring back to the original function?

Here is a typical example.

```
User.prototype.edit = function(req, res) {

  var self = this,
      db = this.app.db;

  db.User.findById('ABCD', function(err, user)) {

    // I cannot use this.foo(user)
    self.foo(user);
  });
};

User.prototype.foo = function(user) {

};
```

Do you normally use this approach or have you found a cleaner solution?

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Comment: how about a solution like call(), apply() or even the ES5's bind() ??

Comment: @Couto, `call` and `apply` still need a reference to `this` which brings you back to the original problem. `bind` is indeed a good solution.

Comment: @davin you're correct indeed, i did not remember that when i wrote the comment. Personally i use bind()

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There are three main ways to deal with `this` in callbacks:

### 1. Create a lexically-scoped variable, as you are currently doing

The two most common names for this new variable are `that` and `self`. I personally prefer using `that` because browsers have a global window property called self and my linter complains if I shadow it.

```
function edit(req, res) {
    var that = this,
    db.User.findById('ABCD', function(err, user){
        that.foo(user);
    });
};
```

One advantage of this approach is that once the code is converted to using `that` you can add as many inner callbacks as you want and they will all seamlessly work due to lexical scoping. Another advantage is that its very simple and will work even on ancient browsers.

### 2. Use the .bind() method.

Javascript functions have a [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method that lets you create a version of them that has a fixed `this`.

```
function edit(req, res) {
    db.User.findById('ABCD', (function(err, user){
        this.foo(user);
    }).bind(this));
};
```

When it comes to handling `this`, the bind method is specially useful for one-of callbacks where having to add a wrapper function would be more verbose:

```
setTimeout(this.someMethod.bind(this), 500);

var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){ that.doSomething() }, 500);
```

The main disadvantage of `bind` is that if you have nested callbacks then you also need to call `bind` on them. Additionally, [IE <= 8 and some other old browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Function.prototype.bind), don't natively implement the `bind` method so you might need to use some sort of [shimming library](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) if you still have to support them.

### 3. If you need more fine-grained control of function scope or arguments, fall back to .call() and .apply()

The more primitive ways to control function parameters in Javascript, including the `this`, are the [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods. They let you call a function with whatever object as their `this` and whatever values as its parameters. `apply` is specially useful for implementing variadic functions, since it receives the argument list as an array.

For example, here is a version of bind that receives the method to bind as a string. This lets us write down the `this` only once instead of twice.

```
function myBind(obj, funcname){
     return function(/**/){
         return obj[funcname].apply(obj, arguments);
     };
}

setTimeout(myBind(this, 'someMethod'), 500);
```

Comment: Some really great answers posted, this one having the best overview. I think I'll stick with my variable assignment, it's simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Interestingly, I just ran a (very simple) benchmark in nodejs, and method 1 was 100x faster than method 2.

Comment: Ran a similar benchmark.  I didn't get 100x faster, but still significantly faster to use the closure method.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks!

Comment: This should be updated with the new lambdas which are great for using the parent "this" context

Comment: @NeeL: Feel free to edit the answer with that extra information. My JS is a tad rusty.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is the well-established way to do this, although `that` is a widespread naming convention for `this` "copy".

You can also try:

```
db.User.findById('ABCD', this.foo.bind(this));
```

But this approach requires `foo()` to have exactly the same signature as the one expected by `findById()` (in your example you are skipping `err`).

Comment: We've also chosen this approach at my work, partly because of this, and partly because using `that` has lower mental overhead to "parse" and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a proxy for the callback with:

```
var createProxy = function(fn, scope) {
  return function () {
    return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
  }; 
};
```

Using this, you could do the following:

```
db.User.findById('ABCD', createProxy(function(err, user)) {
  this.foo(user);
}, this));
```

jQuery does something similar with: [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

And, as others have noted using `bind`, have a look here if compatibility is an issue:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility

Comment: The question is tagged `node.js`, there aren't compatibility issues; `bind` works and should be preferred.

Comment: @davin Ah, missed that. But I guess this might be helpful outside of node.js too, so I'll leave it as it is.