# JavaScript - referencing 'this' in an inner function

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

Consider the following code:

```
MyClass.prototype.my_func = function () {
    this.x = 10;
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (data) {
            alert(this.x);
        }
    });
}
```

It doesn't work, since apparently `this` is not bound into the closure's execution context. I've been able to work it around by introducing another variable:

```
var _this = this;
```

And this works inside the anonymous function. But looks quite ugly to me. Is there some nice way to handle this?

Comment: I think your proposed solution -- `var _this = this;` -- is the standard workaround.

Comment: The standard workaround uses `var that` instead :P

Comment: @LukeH I would go as far as to **not** even call it a *workaround*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may look like the ugly solution for you and there are some walkarounds (such as [using **`bind()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to change the context), but this is the best solution I know of.

Alternatively you can change it to:

```
var self = this;
```

or give it more meaningful name, but it would be better (in this case) not to change the context, as you may need it some day.

Answer (score 1):

You can make usage of `Function.prototype.bind` for that:

```
MyClass.prototype.my_func = function () {
    this.x = 10;
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (data) {
            alert(this.x);
        }.bind(this);
    });
}
```

Now the parent context variable is also bound to the anonymous function.

Comment: @Andy: well, that is very possible. `.bind()` is rather new'ish from the ES5 specs, so it might not be supported by old'ish browsers.

Comment: @Andy: In my answer I gave a link to the MDN article about `bind()` and on how to implement it on older browsers, so you can see it there. But I still think it is not the way to go, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the `this` syntax usually refers to the **object**, not a function. In your case, `this` refers to **MyClass**.

If you're using the variable in the object, you probably forgot to define `x` in `MyClass`.

If you're using the variable within the function ONLY I'd define my variables using the `var` syntax. Variables defined within a function are destroyed when a function ends.

```
MyClass.prototype.my_func = function () {
    var x = 10;

    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (data) {
            alert(x);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closure will have access to all objects defined in its parent's context. So if we have:

```
function() {
  var x = 10;
}
```

Then this is valid:

```
function() {
  var x = 10;

  (function() {
    alert(2*x); // 20
  }())
}
```

Therefore, when you define `var _this = this` you have merely defined a new variable in the parent's context that is available within the closure. See [question #4371333](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern) for more information on this "pattern."