# Get object in member function callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have an object with a method that I’d like to pass to a function as a callback. However, inside the callback, `this` no longer refers to my object. Why not?

I’m familiar with using a variable to get around the problem when passing a function literal:

```
var obj = {
    a: function () {
        var me = this;

        console.log(this);

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(this); // Not obj
            console.log(me);   // This works!
        }, 100);
    }
};
```

How can I fix it in this case?

```
var obj = {
    b: function () {
        setTimeout(this.callback, 100);
    },
    callback: function () {
        console.log(this); // =(
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `this` can be kind of tricky in Javascript. The problem is that its value depends on [how you call the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```
obj.callback(); //ok

var f = obj.callback;
f(); //does not look like a method call
     //Javascript does not pass the this!
```

The usual workaround is passing a wrapper callback like you did in b), except that the common name for the `me` variable is `that` (you sometimes see `self` too)

```
var that = this;
setTimeout( function(){ return that.callback(); }, 300);
```

The other alternative is to use the bind method from functions

```
setTimeout( this.callback.bind(this) , 300)
```

Note that bind is not supported in IE 8 (you might need a shim in that case).

---

For more:

[Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu/7875451#7875451)

Comment: note that Function.prototype.bind is part of ECMAScript5, it will not work on IE6/7/8 and Firefox 3.6 (and less relevant as it auto-updates, older Chromes like < 6)

Comment: It is easier to understand `this` when you think of variables/properties as pointers to functions instead of being functions themselves. `obj.callback` is just a pointer to a function that has no idea who points to it and can infact have any number of pointers to it. So because of this, `this` for the function can only be resolved during call time and has a few simple rules for it. So always remember it's resolved during call-time and life will be easier :)

Comment: this.callback.bind(this) is what I was looking for.