# Maintaining original callback "this" with bind function

Tags: javascript, callback

I understand `bind` creates a new function with the `this` value replaced. The example

```
function edit(req, res) {
    db.User.findById('ABCD', (function(err, user){
        this.foo(user);
    }).bind(this));
};
```

from [Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu)

has the callback function providing its own parameters.

I am using `http.min.js`, which handles callbacks like this:

```
http.get({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/player/status/" + name,
      onload: function() {
        console.log(this.responseText);
```

notice the lack of this passed in - `this.responseText` will give me a string I can parse for `JSON` .

What is the simplest way to maintain the "this" from `http.min.js` callback and bind to my callback function?

I like the syntax of

```
http.get({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/player/status/" + name,
      onload: this.handlePlayerInfo.bind(this);
```

and if possible want to use that, instead of using `var that`.

Using library: https://github.com/quantumpotato/http.min.js/blob/master/http.min.js

Comment: So what happened when you tried it the way you've shown with `.bind()`?

Comment: I'm sure that doesn't work, then you can't access the `this` of `http`.

Comment: If you use bind, you won't be able to access `this` from http. If you don't use bind, you will have to use `var that` in `handlePlayerInfo`.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using `.then()` rather than `onload`? That way you could set `this` to anything you like and receive the response as an argument... (Or does the `onload` handler receive any arguments?)

Comment: nnnnn onload is from the http.min.js library, no arguments. I could modify it, I suppose, is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Thanks Eliott, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: The only http.min library that I could find supports promises, so could solve your issue using .then() instead of onload, i.e., a minor change in your code and no change to the library. (But maybe I was looking at the wrong library. You didn't provide a link.)

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry about that. I'll look for your http.min (post a link?) I'm using: https://github.com/quantumpotato/http.min.js/blob/master/http.min.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using `var that` is the only way to maintain the callback "this" state.

So I'll do

```
Callback.hell = this;
    http.get({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/join/" + Player.name,
      onload: this.handleJoin;
    });

handleJoin(res) {
    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    console.log("join" + j);
    console.log(j.name);
    Callback.hell.status.auth = j.auth;
    Callback.hell.status.name = j.name;
    Callback.hell.getPlayerInfo();
  }
```