# Using update with batch method in a loop in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2-offline

In Firestore, I am trying to update documents in a loop with the batch method.

How come this code works :

```
var batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
var eventRef = this.eventCollection.doc(eventkey).ref;
batch.update(eventRef, updateField );
var artistRef = this.memberCollection.doc('7yLf6RgLIIEUkAJ3jbXy').collection('events').doc(eventkey).ref; 
batch.update(artistRef, updateField); 
var artistRef = this.memberCollection.doc('eJtcLZrUZhhObWcmptQs').collection('events').doc(eventkey).ref; 
batch.update(artistRef, updateField); 
batch.commit().then(function() {console.log('success')};
```

But this one doesn't work :

```
var batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
var eventRef = this.eventCollection.doc(eventkey).ref;
batch.update(eventRef, updateField );
if(artists) {
  Object.values(artists).forEach(function(artist) {
    var artistkey = artist.$key;
    var artistRef = this.memberCollection.doc(artistkey).collection('events').doc(eventkey).ref;
    batch.update(artistRef, updateField); 
  });
}
batch.commit().then(function() {console.log('success')};
```

It tells me "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCollection' of undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're inside a callback function, the meaning of `this` is different from outside of it.

The simplest solution is to assign your `memberCollection` to a separate variable outside of the callback:

```
var batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
var eventRef = this.eventCollection.doc(eventkey).ref;
var memberCollection = this.memberCollection;
batch.update(eventRef, updateField );
if(artists) {
  Object.values(artists).forEach(function(artist) {
    var artistkey = artist.$key;
    var artistRef = memberCollection.doc(artistkey).collection('events').doc(eventkey).ref;
    batch.update(artistRef, updateField); 
  });
}
batch.commit().then(function() {console.log('success')};
```

But you can also use arrow syntax for functions, which prevents the reassigning of `this`:

```
var batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
var eventRef = this.eventCollection.doc(eventkey).ref;
batch.update(eventRef, updateField );
if(artists) {
  Object.values(artists).forEach((artist) => {
    var artistkey = artist.$key;
    var artistRef = this.memberCollection.doc(artistkey).collection('events').doc(eventkey).ref;
    batch.update(artistRef, updateField); 
  });
}
batch.commit().then(function() {console.log('success')};
```

This is an extremely common JavaScript question, and applies everywhere you have callbacks (not just with Firestore). I recommend you check out some of the previous questions on this topic:

- [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
- [Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu)

Comment: thanks Frank for your answer... very precise and complete!