# Javascript this keyword, assigning context-bound function to invoke variable

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the last line of this code work?
How can I make it work without changing Thing or obj?
How can I assign a context-bound function invoking 'obj.getName' to the variable 'f' (that is, the expression 'f()' would result in the invocation of 'obj.getName').?

```
class Thing{
  constructor(name) {this._name = name;}
  getName() { return this._name;}
}

const obj = new Thing('a');
const f = obj.getName;
const name = f();
```

Comment: You need to bind it explicitly: `const f = obj.getName.bind(obj);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu)

Answer (score 1):

This is just explaining why it doesn't work, the solution is already in the comments.

> Why doesn't the last line of this code work

let's break it down to understand it more clearly.

In this line

```
const f = obj.getName;
```

You're copying the function `getName` definition, and setting it to `f`.

`f` now is a normal function like any you would define.

```
let f = function getName() {
  return this._name;
}
```

Now if you'd call that, wouldn't `this` be undefined ?